How to refer to type ID of Shapely geometry by name, e.g. MULTIPOINT?
The documentation at https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/shapely.get_type_id.html lists possible return values of get_type_id() function, e.g. MULTIPOINT is 4. Is MULTIPOINT identifier or something similar available, so I don't have to write cryptic code like:
if get_type_id(geometry) == 4:

in order to test if geometry is a MultiPoint?

You can use the standard python way to determine the class type.
Something like this:
import shapely

if isinstance(geometry, shapely.MultiPoint):


You can use .geom_type, to get the name in plain text:
from shapely.geometry import MultiPoint, Point

mp = MultiPoint([(0,0), (1,1)])
pnt = Point((2,2))

#What methods are available for a multipoint object
for m in dir(mp):
    if "type" in m.lower(): #If "type" is in the method name
        print(m)
# geom_type
# geometryType
# type

#print(mp.geom_type)
#'MultiPoint'

for geom in [mp, pnt]:
    if geom.geom_type.lower()=="multipoint":
        print(geom)
#MULTIPOINT ((0 0), (1 1))

